# Coninue to next iteration in java while reading excel file

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a selenium java function below where i am reading file from excel

Requirement- if my code fails for particular row due to some error message on page, then my should go to next row but iteration do not stop

```
    for (int i = 0; i <rowcount-2; i++) {



                    wait.ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By
                            .id("_FOpt1:_FOr1:0:_FOSritemNode_procurement_supplier_qualification:0:_FOTsditasksId::icon")));



                    WebElement task = driver
                            .findElement(By
                                    .id("_FOpt1:_FOr1:0:_FOSritemNode_procurement_supplier_qualification:0:_FOTsditasksId::icon"));
                    WebElement menu;
                    boolean menuVisible = false;
                    while (!menuVisible) {
                        task.click();
                        wait.ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By
                                .id("_FOpt1:_FOr1:0:_FOSritemNode_procurement_supplier_qualification:0:_FOTRaT:0:RAtl1")));


                        menu = driver
                                .findElement(By
                                        .id("_FOpt1:_FOr1:0:_FOSritemNode_procurement_supplier_qualification:0:_FOTRaT:0:RAtl1"));
                        if (menu.isDisplayed()) {
                            menuVisible = true;
                        }
                    }




                    wait.ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By
                            .id("_FOpt1:_FOr1:0:_FOSritemNode_procurement_supplier_qualification:0:_FOTRaT:0:RAtl1")));

                    driver.findElement(
                            By.id("_FOpt1:_FOr1:0:_FOSritemNode_procurement_supplier_qualification:0:_FOTRaT:0:RAtl1"))
                            .click();

}
```

if it fails inside the loop, it should not stop execution and move to next iteration value 
if it fails for i=1, then it should move to i=2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use try catch block to control the exception case.

for example:

```
for (...){
try {
    //read excel
    //if failed then continue
    } catch (FailedToReadException e) {
        continue;
    }
}
```